# Differences between cano and canto

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In Cap. X of LLPSI, Ørberg introduces the verb [cano](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/cano), having introduced [canto](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/canto) in a previous chapter. The usage of both so far is just *sing*, but are there more nuanced differences between the two?

From the definitions of the two, it seems like *canto* might be a more light-hearted, jovial singing, whereas *cano* might be more, for lack of a better word, "proper" singing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to *[Döderlein's Hand-book of Latin Synonymes](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=n_UjEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=%22Canere%20(from%20%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%87%CE%B5%E1%BF%96%CE%BD)%20means%22&source=bl&ots=RRAEufJd2Y&sig=ACfU3U2FHSggfMGTaKYFeUsoaYnc5PV0ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8-cSNqrXwAhUjRjABHSdRDDoQ6AEwAXoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=%22Canere%20(from%20%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%87%CE%B5%E1%BF%96%CE%BD)%20means%22&f=false)* (also [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm)), *canere* is the more general term for music (and thus may be used for singing), whereas *cantare* usually is used more specifically to refer to vocal music:

> **Canere** (from καναχεῖν) means, in the most general sense, to make
> music, voce, tibiis, fidibus, like μέλπειν; **cantare**, with vocal music,
> like ἀείδειν;
>
> (emphasis added)

(**Note**: Döderlein's assertion that *canere* is from καναχεῖν is incorrect. According to da Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary*, the possible Greek cognates are ἠικανός, "singing early", as in the case of a cock; or  κανχή, "noise".)

According to Lewis and Short, *[cantare](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=cantare&la=la#lexicon)* can also be used for music that isn't vocal, but they note:

> **canto:**
>
> Less freq. of instrumental music, and only with abl. of the instrument (cf. cano)

*Cantare* may also include such things as the sounds of birds or fowl, as well as enchantments, charms, incantations.

According to Lewis and Short, *[canere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=cano&la=la#lexicon)* includes many other things that aren't usually associated with *cantare*. *Canere* may include, besides the sound of birds, that of frogs as well. It can also mean such things as *to rehearse*, *recite*, *prophesy*, *foretell*, *predict*, *celebrate*, *blow*, *sound* and *resound*.

Cicero, for example, used *canere* in the more general sense to speak of the playing of flutes:

> *Si ex oliva modulate **canentes tibiae** nascerentur, num dubitares, quin*
> *inesset in oliva tibicini quaedam scientia?* (Cicero, *[De Natura Deorum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=urn:cts:latinLit:phi0474.phi050.perseus-lat1:2.22)*)
>
> If melodiously playing flutes were born from the olive tree, would you
> not doubt that there exists in the olive tree some knowledge of
> playing the flute?

Comment: Should be noted that the notion that Latin *canere* is from Greek καναχεῖν is total nonsense.

Comment: @Cairnarvon. Thanks. I made a note of it.

Comment: It does look though quite similar to Japanese _kanaderu_ (to play a musical instrument) :-)