# How to translate "Be still and listen, the earth is singing"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to have something inscribed with this phrase, but in Latin:

"Be still and listen, the earth is singing"

Comment: Oh, thank you so very much for your invaluable help, and such informative answers. I am very much in awe of your knowledge...I did manage to attain an 'O' level in Latin but that was more than forty years ago. In the intervening years a lot of water has flowed under that particular bridge and washed away pretty much everything I ever knew!

Answer (score 3):

“Tacē et audī, Terra cantat.”

Or, if addressing several people rather than one:

“Tacēte et audīte, Terra cantat.”

Alternatively, use silē /silēte instead of tacē / tacēte. Tacē is more about not speaking, while silē would be more about not making sounds in general, which includes speaking, but isn't limited to it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd offer something like this:

> Sileamus atque audiamus, terra enim canit.
>
> Let us be quiet and listen, for the earth is singing.

You can opt for sile/silete and audi/audite if you prefer direct commands, but I think an exhortation sounds better, and includes the speaker in the command as well.

Latin mottoes are free to ignore conjunctions (*enim*, "for"), but in a complete sentence like this, it's preferable to include one.

I chose *silere* over *tacere*, since the former is "stronger than" the latter, according to Lewis and Short. It's more than just a "be quiet", but "be still." It's a very subtle difference in nuance, and one that I believe isn't always held up in practice.

I also chose *canere* over *cantare*, since the former is explicitly used of animals singing (and the Platonic spheres).

Comment: Good point about canere vs cantare. For the curious, here's an entry that goes over the difference: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15950/differences-between-cano-and-canto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134648/discussion-between-cmw-and-florianus).